# Simulating finding a randomly chosen number by asking binary questions

Tags: matlab, random, octave, probability, entropy

As a question in an assignment, I have been asked to write an Octave function that simulates 1000 experiments of finding a Random Variable *X* with alphabet *{0, 1, 2, 3}* and pmf:

*Px(0) = 1/8*

*Px(1) = 1/4*

*Px(2) = 1/2*

*Px(3) = 1/8*

by asking a sequence of binary, "yes" or "no" questions.

I have determined that the optimal sequence of binary questions asked to find the value of *X* is to simply ask *"Is X = p?"* where p are the possible values, in order of decreasing probabilty.

So the optimal sequence would be:

1. *Is X = 2?*

   If not:
2. *Is X = 1?*

   If not:
3. *Is X = 0?*

   If not then *X = 3*

This is the function I have written:

```
function x = guessing_experiment(probabilities, n)
  % generates n simulations of finding a random number in an alphabet by asking binary questions,
  % where 'probabilities' is a list of the probabilities per number in the order the questions will be asked

  num_Qs = zeros(1,n);                            % allocate array of size n for number of questions asked per experiment
  [num_col, alphabet_size] = size(probabilities); % get size of alphabet

  for i = 1:n                                     % generate n experiments
    Qs = 0;                                       % number of questions asked in this experiment
    for j = 1:alphabet_size - 1                   % iterate through questions
      question = rand;                            % generate random number in range [0, 1]
      Qs++;                                       % incremenet number of questions asked
      if (question <= probabilities(j))           % if question produces a "yes" answer
        break;
      endif
    endfor
    num_Qs(i) = Qs;                               % store number of questions asked for this experiment
  endfor

  x = mean(num_Qs);                               % calculate mean number of questions asked over the n experiments 

 end
```

Which is called as `guessing_experiment([1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/8], 1000)`
where the array is the probability of each question producing a "yes" answer, in order of how they are to be asked, and *n* is the number of experiments.

Asking these questions should produce an average number of questions of 1.75, but my program is always producing an average of ~1.87. Where is my script in error?

I am assuming it has something to do with generating a new random number to simulate each of the 3 questions being asked.

Comment: To me it seems that the algorithm is correct, and that the average number of questions asked is actually `1.875`.

Comment: @UJIN, could the average number of questions not be calculated as 1*P(X=2)+2*(X=1)+3*(X=0 or X=3) which is 1*(1/2)+2*(1/4)+3*(1/8+1/8) = 1.75?

Comment: I always had my issues with probability theory, so I can't really bring much math support to my comment (and that's why it's a comment). The only thing that was putting me off was the fact that your average seems to go towards a 'nice' `1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125` value. Intuitively it seems you are right, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my previous wrong answer which was stated the your script is right and your calculation is wrong. I think about it once more and your calculation is right. I tried it myself using the following MATLAB script:

```
% probabilities for each number
p = [1/8,1/4,1/2,1/8];
% sort them from higher to lower
p = sort(p,'descend');
% number of questions per probability
nq = 1:length(p)-1;
% the last question can distinguish between two variables
nq(end+1) = nq(end);
% number of trials
n = 100000;
% random sample number of questions
q = randsample(nq,n,true,p);
% mean number of questions
avgQ = mean(q)
```

and the obtained avg. was 1.75 - as you calculated.
I will try to take another look on your code to see what's wrong

**EDIT**

the problem with your script is that you ignored the [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), i.e., when asking questions about the variable you ignored the information you already know about it. for example, when you're asking your third question, the probability that the value will be `0` is *not* `p=1/8` but `p=1/2` because you already know that it is not `1` or `2`. 
The fix you need to do is as dividing the probability by the possible events probabilities `probabilities(j)/sum(probabilities(j:end))`:

```
n = 10000;
p = [1/8,1/4,1/2,1/8];
% sort them from higher to lower
probabilities = sort(p,'descend');
probabilities(end-1) = probabilities(end-1) + probabilities(end);
probabilities(end) = [];
alphabet_size = numel(probabilities);
num_Qs = zeros(1,n);                            % allocate array of size n for number of questions asked per experiment

for i = 1:n                                     % generate n experiments
    Qs = 0;                                       % number of questions asked in this experiment
    for j = 1:alphabet_size                   % iterate through questions
        question = rand;                            % generate random number in range [0, 1]
        Qs = Qs + 1;                                       % incremenet number of questions asked
        if question < probabilities(j)/sum(probabilities(j:end))           % if question produces a "yes" answer
            break;
        end
    end
    num_Qs(i) = Qs;                               % store number of questions asked for this experiment
end

x = mean(num_Qs)
```

x ~ 1.75

the vector of *conditional* probabilities in this scenario is:

```
p = [1/8,1/4,1/2,1/8];
p = sort(p,'descend');
cond_p = p./cumsum(p,'reverse')

cond_p =

    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    1.0000
```